# st_as_sf() gives two integers in the geometry instead of proper coordinates

Tags: spatial

So, I have a dataframe with two columns; X and Y coordinates such as 10.373737 and 29.474744 but when I use this object in the st_as_sf function like:

```
data_sf = st_as_sf(data, coords = c("X","Y"), crs = 4326)
```

I get geometries such as POINT(3, 26). And this is not what I want to have. I want an sf object but in the proper coordinate system.

Unfortunately, I simply do not see where is the issue.

When I check my sf object it is in the WG84 system.